# load wcf hosted on console app with app.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Hello im making wcf hosted in console app is possible to load this service with app.config?

```
ChannelFactory<IService> service = new ChannelFactory<IService>();
service.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
IService channel = service.CreateChannel();
Console.Read();
```

This is start of my wcf into console app but how to load wcf config?

Im new in wcf so please be polite for me.

--edit---

So i get errorr
s zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.

```
            ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Contracs.Service));
            serviceHost.Open();
```

and my app.config is

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <configuration>
              <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="Contracs.Service">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="Contracs.IService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Service" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: Is Contracs.Service the full namespace?

Comment: namespace Contracs this is namespace should i change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF will by default try to load from the app config.

Here is some more info:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)